# Using AppStats on GAE with NDB, how can I tell what query is executing?

Tags: google-app-engine, appstats

I'm looking at RPC calls, but the stack is all tasklet and ndb. This is making it difficult for me to tell what queries are running. Is there an appstats config setting I need to use?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In appengine_config.py add: (Your code calls won't make it into the query stack without this)

```
appstats_MAX_STACK = 20
```

In AppStats, under Requests History, click on a request.

In RPC Call Traces click "+" for a datastore_v3.RunQuery

In the stack trace you can see links to your code that was executed.